# Ternary operator return `True` instead the given value

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm using ternary operator for short conditional variable definition. I was wondering when the expression returned True instead given in the expression value.

```
>>> digits = '123456'

>>> conv_d = digits != None if int(digits) else None

>>> conv_d
>>> True

>>> int(digits)
>>> 123456
```

Explain to me please, how this happens? What is the logical difference between a ternary operator and regular conditional expression in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int(digits) == 123456` which is a true-ish value. So `conv_d = digits != None`. Since `digits` is not `None`, `conv_d` is set to true.

You probably wanted this:

```
conv_d = int(digits) if digits is not None else None
```

Remember that a string containing something not a number will raise an exception though! If you prefer 0 or None for those values, write a small function:

```
def toint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return None # or 0
```

Answer (score 5):

The Python conditional operator is not in the same order as in other languages. And you should never compare equality with `None` unless you're certain that you need to.

```
conv_d = int(digits) if digits is not None else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to ternary-operators:

conv_d = digits != None and int(digits) or None #short-circuiting; just wrong in this context as it doesn't work for digits = "0" -  please see comment(s) below

or

conv_d = int(digits) if digits is not None else None

The second expression is clearer, hence preferred.

Comment: The first will fail if `int(digits)` is 0. Both will fail if `digits` doesn't compare equality fairly with `None`.

Comment: Thanks for catching the first error! The idea was simply to show that there were a couple of alternatives in Python to the missing ternary operator, so I simply assumed digits to be either an str composed of [0-9] or None (ThiefMaster's response covers this issue anyway). Given that, I agree that when comparing with None, "is not" is the preferred operator.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the keywords are placed. "X if Y else Z". "Y" is the part that follows "if", so it is the condition. "X if Y" is a perfectly valid (though less common) English construction meaning the same thing as "if Y, X", thus X is the expression evaluated when Y is satisfied. Z is the expression evaluated when Y is not satisfied, similarly.